# Selenium RC does not open firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

When I use the Selenium RC 1.0.3 on windows everything works fine.
When I config the client to use selenium on Ubuntu 10.10 what happens is that the RemoteRunner is opening and showing Command History as if everything works fine, But the other window of firefox does not open hence the test does not run.

I"m pretty sure I misconfiged something on the server, But what is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what happens in RC's command line. If it opens firefox window, but doesnt navigate further - then you need to set firefox to use proxy with the same address and port as your RC. And if it doesn't open at all, then it probably doesn't know where firefox is located, so you need to pass path along with browser definition. This is done either in test case file, or if you use selenium grid, in grid_configuration.yml

```
*firefox /usr/lib/firefox-5.0/firefox.sh
```

upd. some say that shell scripts are not good with selenium